# Stop sudo stopping script completion

Tags: bash, sudo

How to stop the sudo program stopping the script from completing ? 
Sudo prompts for a password , it always fails on the first attempt , the second attempt it succeeds , but stops the script from completing . 
 The script will stop and any commands after the prompt for the password , will not be executed . 
 The hi on line 7 of the script will not be executed . 
 How do i stop sudo from stopping the rest of the script from completing ?

```
sudo bash << 'END'
    cat << 'DONE' > /usr/bin/hi
        echo hi
DONE
    sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/hi
END
hi
```

Comment: sudo will wait for you to enter the password. Is that what you are referring to by 'stopping'?

Comment: Also, you don't need `sudo` before the `chmod` call here, because it is already running under `sudo`.

Comment: I edited the question . What i mean by stopping is sudo asks for a password  then stops all the next commands in the script from executing .

Comment: To expand on what other are saying here, your *first* sudo runs as the user you're logged in as, but the *second* sudo runs as root, which is redundant from a security perspective but perhaps helpful for logging. Rather than using a heredoc, you might find it clearer to run your bash commands inline, for example `echo "echo hi" | sudo bash -c 'cat > $0; chmod +x $0' /usr/bin/hi`

Answer (score 0):

If your script needs root privileges, you will have to provide them at some point.
Run your script as root.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is more:

```
sudo bash << 'END'
   cat << 'DONE' > /usr/bin/hi
      echo hi
DONE
   chmod +x /usr/bin/hi
END
hi
```

note that I moved the chmod out of the `/usr/bin/hi` file, as you seem to want this file to be executable, not to change its own rights.

BTW, I also removed the 2nd sudo which is useless as you are already in a sudo context.

EDIT: following question edit:

Actually, when you perform a command with sudo, you (usually) need to give your password, and then root credential are held "for a little while", that is why you are asked a password the first time but not the second time.

To prevent being asked for a password, you need to edit the sudoers file (with `visudo` command) and add the program you want to run to the command allowed with no password asked (read the documentation in the file, or `man sudoers`). Nevertheless, giving those kind of unlimited restrictions is quite dangerous, espacially in this case because the program will be `bash`, thus you will be able to run a console as root. Being able to sudo as root is already a great responsibility, without password is almost like using a shell as root, thus quite risky (especially for the system, if you do a mistake while doing a command or an update of your script).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is not stopping execution of the commands after `sudo`.
All these commands are being executed *under* `sudo`.
In other words, `sudo` runs first. Then it calls `bash` and other commands are just supplied to it as here-doc.

You can use the `-S` option of `sudo` as below:

```
sudo -S bash << 'END'
root123
    cat << 'DONE' > /usr/bin/hi
        echo hi
DONE
    chmod +x /usr/bin/hi
END
hi
```

Replace `root123` by your user's password here. You would have to enter it in plain text in the script.

Effectively, the here-doc is consumed by `sudo`+`bash`.

Other options that can be tried are to use `SUDO_ASKPASS`. Check `man sudo` for more details.

Comment: password=`zenity --password`; echo $password . Does not work .

Comment: ^^ Try adding this line at the start of the script: `export SUDO_ASKPASS="zenity --password" `

Comment: Did you try the plaintext version using `-S` ?